# Global (or static) Method for Detecting whether Speaker is busy?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Android's [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class has a method that tells me whether it is playing or not: [isPlaying()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29)

But that is for a particular instance of [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to which I have access.

Is there a way to tell whether *any* sound is currently being emitted through the phone's **speaker**?

That is, even from other applications to which I have no access and I don't control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of an authoritative and verifiable answer, I will be answering this question as:

**No**, there isn't a way to tell whether any sound is currently being emitted through the phone's speaker.